fstab ignores username configuration
I'm struggling to find a solution to this random issue.
I have the following configuration:
//192.168.1.39/MediaCenter /media/NAS/MediaCenter cifs username=USER1,password=PASSWORD1,uid=1000
//192.168.1.39/home/Photos /media/NAS/HomePhotosUSER1 cifs ro,_netdev,noserverino,username=USER1,password=PASSWORD1,uid=1000
//192.168.1.39/home/Photos /media/NAS/HomePhotosUSER2 cifs ro,_netdev,noserverino,username=USER2,password=PASSWORD2,uid=1000
//192.168.1.39/home/Photos /media/NAS/HomePhotosUSER3 cifs ro,_netdev,noserverino,username=USER3,password=PASSWORD3,uid=1000

This is to map 4 folders from a Synology NAS to my Ubuntu computer.
The first line has worked like this for probably 3 years without any issues.
For the other 3, the folder for the USER1 is sometimes replaced with the USER2 or USER3 content. It's as if it is grabbing the configuration for users 2 or 3 and applying it to the user folder.
Currently, the USER3 photos are shown in the folder for the USER1; one month ago, I got the same issue but with pictures from USER2.
Last time i deleted the folders restarted and remounted and solved the issue but now is showing again.
example showing the same pictures in both folders

You are trying to mount the same share (//192.168.1.39/home/Photos) to three different mount.points and with three different User/Passwords. I am not sure how that should work. What command do you use to mount those shares ?

yes, the mount point is the same, the thing that changes is the user that is accessing.
with your comment I think I got an idea, I can try to change the USER accessing to the folders to be the ADMIN used that have the path as Homes/USER1/HOME/PHOTOSto check if it helps with the issue

fixing typo above:
With that user I can set the path as  Homes/USER1/HOME/PHOTOSto check if it helps with the issue
